# Tensorflow can't find Graphic Card

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

Python don't see Graphic card. Used official documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu)

Install CUDA 11.2, cuDNN 8.1, tensorflow: 2.11.0/2.10.0. Also used several videos from Youtube, but still doesn't work.

Graphic card: 1650

I try to predict stock price and want to use Tensorflow GPU.

1. Installed Visual Studio Installer and install all necessary components.
2. Install Cuda 11.2
3. Install Graphic Card driver
4. Set up cuCNN 8.1
5. Set up PATH for CUDA
6. Also was used tensorflow-gpu and tensorflow

But still don't receive any result.

Graphic Card: Nvidia GeForce 1650

Also was install required versions of tensorflow-gpu.

Fix it. Just use CONDA:

Create new Enviroment and after:

```
conda install cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1
```

Comment: Are you on windows? Try to install ``tensorflow-gpu`` through the [Conda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution). It will also download required Cuda and cuDNN for you.

Comment: Did you checked your CUDA installation using `nvidia-smi` command?

Comment: Yes, was install required versions of tensorflow-gpu. Try several times, so problem not in tensorflow-gpu

Comment: Try using another code editor or IDE. Visual Studio (2022) is not specifically built for Python, though it is compatible with it. Try using Visual Studio Code or Pycharm and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it. Just use CONDA:

Create new Enviroment and after:

```
conda install cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1
```